# Fields not persisting using MappedSuperclass in Symfony 2/Doctrine 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

A `MappedSuperclass`:

```php
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
abstract class AbstractMessage
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true) */
    protected $content;
}
```

And a child subclass, redefining `$content` to add some custom validation asserts:

```php
/** @ORM\Entity */
class InternalMessage extends AbstractMessage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Internal message title is required.")
     */
    protected $content;

    /** @return integer */
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }

    /**
     * @param string $content
     * @return InternalMessage
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
        return $this;
    }

    /** @return string */
    public function getContent() { return $this->content; }
}
```

## When `$content` override parent

As in my example, `$content` is not persisted! `null` field...

## Removing `$content` from the child

If i remove `$content` from `InternalMessage` field is persisted, while validation does not work anymore.

Is this a bug or something? I opened an [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5156) but don't know if it's the right place (i'm new to how github works).

Too bad i realized that Doctrine inheritance is buggy (starting from the generator itself...).

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me, although what Stof said on the GitHub issue is correct.. They should be protected properties, but if even that's not working then it seems like a more deep rooted problem to me

Comment: @Jaitsu thanks for your support. This is driving me crazy for all the night, hope that we can find a solution (apart form moving all fields in the subclasses, 3 actually)...

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't make sense for you to have to do that. What if you wanted to keep the abstract class' column definition, but just change the validation? (like you're trying to do). It seems like a perfectly valid concept, and pretty powerful if it works

Comment: It seems perfectly normal that $content be persist, no ?

Comment: Seeing as you have `$content` already mapped in your SuperClass, why do you also define it in your `InternalMessage` class? Just define the  `setContent()` and `getContent()`. I may be wrong here, so if I am: please enlighten me further.

Comment: @tolgap just for validation. Imagine many subclasses, each with a different validation rule on the same field (`$content`). Right now, i have `Newsletter` and `SMS` subclasses. `$content` for newsletter has no restrictions, while for SMS should be (say) 766 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, it can't be done, Doctrine2 inheritance strategy doesn't allow you to re-define properties from `MappedSuperClass`.

This should be limitation due the Reflection system.

Your best bet is to extract your validation configuration and move it to a standalone `XML` or `YML` file.

You may also want to do it for your ORM (but you'll need to do it for all entities in your Bundle) as it will allow you more flexibility.